# Passing Akka Actor Reference to other Actors

Tags: akka

I have an Actor that I create from with another Actor (parent). I also spawn several other Actor's from within the parent. The tree looks like:

```
ParentActor
 -- ServiceActor
 -- ProcessActor1
 -- ProcessActor2
```

Now I want to pass around this ServiceActor instance to ProcessActor instances, but the problem is that the ServiceActor could choke and be killed at some point. I handle this in my parent and I would have a Restart policy for the ServiceActor.

Now my question is say if I create all my Actors as mentioned above and after a couple of hours the ServiceActor gets Restarted because of an Exception happening, should I re-instantiate my ProcessActor's?

Is the old ServiceActor ActorRef reference still valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ActorRef` is valid even if the underlying actor is restarted multiple times. From the official [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/actors.html#initialization-patterns):

> The rich lifecycle hooks of Actors provide a useful toolkit to implement various initialization patterns. During the lifetime of an `ActorRef`, an actor can potentially go through several restarts, where the old instance is replaced by a fresh one, invisibly to the outside observer who only sees the `ActorRef`.

Comment: Does it only apply to Restarts or does this also apply when I discard the old instance and create a new one using context.actorOf(...)?

Comment: It applies only to restarts, you need actor selections to cover cases where you discard an instance and create a new one.